# Пинг через консоль windows

Tags: windows, cmd, ping

Нужна команда для непрерывного пинга определенного хоста и постоянной записи результата пинга в файл с временной меткой для разборок с провайдером. 
`ping google.com -t > log.txt` не помагает, потому что пинг прерывается сообщением "При проверке связи не удалось обнаружить узел google.com. Проверьте имя узла и повторите попытку". Узел провайдера пингуется без проблем, собственно надо доказать недееспособность интернета с помощью лога

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вероятно, подойдёт использование ip-адреса вместо имени:

```
ping -t 8.8.8.8 >log.txt
```

> есть ли возможность добавить временную метку?

```
:check
date /t >>log.txt
time /t >>log.txt
ping -n 1 8.8.8.8 >>log.txt
echo. >>log.txt
timeout 1
goto check
```

Команды `timeout` в XP не было. Там она [заменяется `ping`ом](//stackoverflow.com/q/1672338/4928642).

Comment: работает, однако есть ли возможность добавить временную метку?

Comment: @Umer, дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже задавался вопросом непрерывного пинга с логгированием и временными метками. Написал бат-файл:

```
@echo off
rem pinger v2.1
setlocal>nul
rem в этот файл будет выведен лог работы команды ПИНГ
set filelogname="outlog.txt"
rem адрес, который следует пинговать
set iptoping="8.8.8.8"
cls
echo ping %iptoping% ........ 

rem время в формате 23:15:51,50
set xxa=%TIME%

rem дата в формате 07.09.2016
set xxd=%DATE%

rem формирование трех имен для временных файлов вида
rem ~0809201630121088.tmpp1
rem ~0809201630121089.tmpp1
rem ~0809201630121080.tmpp1


rem формирование строки текущего времени (для назв. временн. файлов)

rem кол-во единиц часов+кол-во минут+кол-во секунд+кол-во д.секунд (без раздел.)
set xxb=%xxa:~-10,1%%xxa:~-8,2%%xxa:~-5,2%%xxa:~-2,2%

rem кол-во десятков часов
set xxc=%xxa:~-11,1%

rem если десятков часов нет, то дописать в xxb впереди тройку
rem иначе дописать впереди xxb кол-во десятков часов
if -%xxc%==- (set xxb=3%xxb%) else set xxb=%xxc%%xxb%

rem если число часов xxb = 0(формат времени с ведущ.0) -то дописать впереди 3
if -%xxb:~0,1%==-0 set xxb=3%xxb%

rem дни+месяцы+годы+время(xxb) -- всё без разделителей
set out1=%xxd:~0,2%%xxd:~3,2%%xxd:~6,4%%xxb%

rem out1 без последней цифры
set out2=%out1:~0,-1%

rem последняя цифра out1
set xxa=%out1:~-1%

rem прибавить 2 к последней цифре out1
set /a xxa+=2

rem out2 + последний знак из xxa 
set out3=%out2%%xxa:~-1%

set /a xxa-=1
set out2=%out2%%xxa:~-1%


rem создание временного файла и вывод в него

rem получили три различных имени файла без точек
set out1=~%out1%.tmpp1
set out2=~%out2%.tmpp1
set out3=~%out3%.tmpp1

rem удаление старых временных файлов
del %TEMP%\*.tmpp1

rem вывод даты в лог
date /t > %filelogname%



:loop
rem пауза в одну сек с небольшим, между основными пингами (-n 3 = 2сек и т.д.)
ping -n 2 localhost > nul

rem вывод результатов ОДНОГО пинга в файл out1
ping %iptoping% -n 1 > %TEMP%\%out1%

rem вывод текущего времени в файл out2 (с лишним "введите" "текущее" и т.п.)
echo.|time > %TEMP%\%out2%

rem вывод времени в out3 (чистый вид с миллисекундами)
for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (%TEMP%\%out2%) do if -%%a==-Текущее (echo %%c > %TEMP%\%out3%)

rem файл аут2 больше не нужен
del /q %TEMP%\%out2%

rem создадим переменную времени timedata вида 00:00:00 (отсекая миллисек.)
for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in (%TEMP%\%out3%) do set timedata=%%a

rem различный вывод при <1мс >=1мс и превыш. интервала ожидания
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7" %%a in (%TEMP%\%out1%) do if -%%a==-Ответ (if -%%f==-время^<1мс (
echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e время^^^<1мс %%g > %TEMP%\%out3% 
) else (echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g > %TEMP%\%out3%)
)else if -%%a==-Превышен (echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e > %TEMP%\%out3%)

rem создадим переменную пинга
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%TEMP%\%out3%) do set pingdata=%%a

rem запишем полученные данные в выходной файл, добавив метку времени
echo %timedata% %pingdata% >> %filelogname%
goto loop
```